# Android - multiple layouts in one setContentView() - is it possible?

Tags: java, android

Like I did:

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.addcontact);

            imageButton01 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            imageButton01.setOnClickListener(this);

            @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {

        if (view == imageButton01) 
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);

        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO) 
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {   

                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");                
                imageButton01.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    

            } 
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
            {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            } 
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to duplicate "setContentView();", "findViewById();" and other methods, or something like that? I'd like to use this same code to use the camera while click in an imageButton, but with different ones, in different layouts.

Comment: In this type of scenario we should used Fragment.

Comment: How should I use Fragment on this case?

Comment: You can use `setContentView()` multiple times but only one layout will be loaded.

Comment: if you want to add 2 layouts to one screen, make a new rootlayout containing both layouts as children